# Regex to match all groups between more than one space

Tags: regex

I've got a string

`198.21      543                   G110P0GHTT     SAW         GHA + DBA       11998`

And I'd like to match all groups of the string between spaces. So far I've come up with `(?<=\s)(.*?)(?=\s)` which matches all but the first group. Additionally, this does not count the `GHA + DBA` as a group. What can I add to this to ensure it includes the first record as well as anything MORE than one space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to use look arounds here. Just use this regex to match a non-whitespace string or substring separated by a single space:

```
\S+(?:\s\S+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWdFHN/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\S+`: Match 1+ non-space characters
- `(?:\s\S+)*`: Match 0 or more non-space substring separated by a single space.

Comment: Might be better to use `[^ ]+(?: [^ ])*` since OP said spaces, not all whitespace characters.

Comment: Yes @CAustin, that might be better if there are just spaces in string but probably you meant `[^ ]+(?: [^ ]+)*`

Comment: @CAustin In terms of performance both solutions take 82 steps according to regex101. In terms of brevity, `\S+(?: \S+)*` would win. As for readability, you're just splitting hairs. Also, yours has a typo, it should be `[^ ]+(?: [^ ]+)*`.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The point isn't performance, it's matching exactly what's intended. My bad on the typo.

Comment: @anubhava out of curiosity, how might I grab specific matches out of this? For instance if I want the third match and fourth match only.

Comment: It depends upon the tool/language you're using for regex. In Javascript or python or php you get an array of matches.

Comment: So something along the lines of `{2}` couldn't be added to this to get that matched index?

Comment: No, regex doesn't need any change. Getting 2nd or 4th element is something you do in post processing after getting all matches in an array.