# One regex to capture words separated by one space-character in combination with the opposite capture occurrences more than one space-character

Tags: regex-group

I would like to have just one regex to capture words separated by one space-character in combination with the opposite capture occurrences more than one space-character

I would like to have the following example covered:

```
This line with     sometimes more than    1  space needs to be captured in 3 matches with 2 groups.
```

I expect the following groups:

```
([This line with][     ])([sometimes more than][    ])([1][  ])space needs to be captured in 3 matches with 2 groups.
```

To capture one of the two is no problem. 
i.e. 
to capture more than one space-char:

```
([\s]{2,})
```

and to capture words separated by only one space-char(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288115/3710053):

```
\S+(?:\s\S+)*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either a word followed by a repeating pattern of a single space and a word OR match 2 or more spaces

```
\S+(?: \S+)*| {2,}
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `(?: \S+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `|` Or
- `{2,}` Repeat 2 or more times matching a space

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P85v2c/2)

If you want to match whitespace chars instead, you could replace the space with `\s` but note that it could also possibly match newlines.

*Edit*

For the updated question, you could use 2 capturing groups:

```
(\S+(?: \S+)*)( {2,})
```

**Explanation**

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars
  - `(?: \S+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a space and 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `{2,}` Match 2 or more spaces
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jodPso/3)

Comment: That is almost exactly what I need. I will edit the question.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed Do you mean like this? `\S+(?: \S+)* {2,}`  https://regex101.com/r/lwMzUC/1

Comment: Not exactly. I want to have every match have to groups. One group with the multiple spaces and one group with the words (bind by one space)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208198/discussion-between-siebe-jongebloed-and-the-fourth-bird).