# Struggling parse key value pairs into array with space in key names

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to parse part out a windows event message into key/value pairs but I am struggling to figure out how to do this. It comes in from the WinCollect agent so I am not really able to do much to format the origiThe main issue is that the key names have spaces in them (I.E. SID  Account Name, Security ID, Logon ID) and I need to PascalCase them removing the space. Complicating matters, the value's often have a space after the equals and often times there is no value for the key. The messages often vary and I can't for the life me figure out a simple JavaScript function to tackle this. You'll notice after the LastKey Value pair (Logon Guid) it's just a giant message string I'd like to discard.

Here's the sample string:

```
Subject=  Security ID=   SID  Account Name=  -  Account Domain=  -  Logon ID=  0x0  Logon Information=  Logon Type=  3  Restricted Admin Mode= -  Virtual Account=  No  Elevated Token=  Yes  Impersonation Level=  Impersonation  New Logon=  Security ID=  MDITMonSvc  Account Name=  MonSvc  Account Domain=  MD3T.CE-IT.NET  Logon ID=  0xAE5D3D4  Linked Logon ID=  0x0  Network Account Name= -  Network Account Domain= -  Logon GUID=  {e2fe21c6-1533-f673-af2c-1e289f01739f}  Process Information=  Process ID=  0x0  Process Name=  -  Network Information=  Workstation Name= -  Source Network Address= 11.300.2.35  Source Port=  49357  Detailed Authentication Information=  Logon Process=  Kerberos  Authentication Package= Kerberos  Transited Services= -  Package Name (NTLM only)= -  Key Length=  0  This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.  The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.  The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).  The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.  The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.  The impersonation level field indicates the extent to which a process in the logon session can impersonate.  The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.  - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.  - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.  - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.  - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
```

From the above string I'd expect to have the following values:

```
keyValueArr[0] = "Subject=";
keyValueArr[1] = "SecurityID=";
keyValueArr[2] = "SIDAccountName=-";
keyValueArr[3] = "AccountDomain=-";
keyValueArr[4] = "LogonID=0xAE5D3D4";
keyValueArr[5] = "LogonInformation=";
keyValueArr[6] = "LogonType=3";
keyValueArr[7] = "RestrictedAdminMode=-";
//etc
```

Can't figure out how to do this! Any ideas?

EDIT:
Pavel Savva provided a fantastic answer below for my original string:

```
const regex = /(?:\S+(?:\s\S+)*|\s{2,})=/g

const keys = input.match(regex)
const values = input.split(regex)

const keysAndValues = []

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const key = keys[i].replace(/\s+/g, '')
  let value = values[i + 1].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()

  if (i === keys.length - 1) {
        value = value.split(/\s{2}/).shift()
  }

  const kv = [key, value].join('')

  keysAndValues.push(kv)
}
```

But sometimes the event comes in as this:

```
Dns query= RuleName= - UtcTime= 2023-03-14 17=29=56.244 ProcessGuid= {FBE8C53C-AF2D-6410-401C-000000004100} ProcessId= 3892 QueryName= kbrunette.chi.NET QueryStatus= 0 QueryResults= ==ffff=10.58.2.45; Image= C=Windowssystem32wbemwmiprvse.exe
```

Any ideas on how to make Pavel's solution work with this type of format as well?

Comment: Can the values of each field contain spaces or `-`? Parsing questions tend to be received poorly because you basically need to give us the entire spec of the input for an answer. (also, show what you've tried)

Comment: So what distinguishes between `Subject=;SecurityID=;SIDAccountName=-;` and `Subject=Security;ID=SID;AccountName=-;`?

Comment: Are Windows events not better structured? Why do you get them as a string?

Comment: @MisterJojo "*You'll notice after the LastKey Value pair (Logon Guid) it's just a giant message string I'd like to discard.*" - I'm pretty certain that refers to the unreadable part that your edit moved from data to text

Comment: @MisterJojo yup Bergi is right that last portion should be a part of the data string, not the post itself. Check the examples here: https://www.ultimatewindowssecurity.com/securitylog/encyclopedia/event.aspx?eventID=4624

Answer (score 1):

For sure not the most elegant solution, but I hope it helps...

Looking around the Internet (and specifically [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1135025/4625-event-id-shows-own-pc-name-as-the-account-nam)) it looks like the second and third values should be:

```
eyValueArr[1] = "SecurityID=SID";
keyValueArr[2] = "AccountName=-";
```

With that assumption in mind, `(?:\S+(?:\s\S+)*|\s{2,})=` (shamelessly stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60320932/one-regex-to-capture-words-separated-by-one-space-character-in-combination-with) with a non-capturing group added to account for `=`) seems to work reasonably well to match all the keys:

[image: regex keys match]

We can then split on the regex and build our key-value pairs:

```
const regex = /(?:\S+(?:\s\S+)*|\s{2,})=/g

const keys = input.match(regex)
const values = input.split(regex)

const keysAndValues = []

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const key = keys[i].replace(/\s+/g, '')
  let value = values[i + 1].replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()

  if (i === keys.length - 1) {
        value = value.split(/\s{2}/).shift()
  }

  const kv = [key, value].join('')

  keysAndValues.push(kv)
}
```

Above I'm making the assumption that the last value ends with two spaces in a row.

And this results in:

```
"Subject="
"SecurityID=SID"
"AccountName=-"
"AccountDomain=-"
"LogonID=0x0"
"LogonInformation="
"LogonType=3"
"RestrictedAdminMode=-"
"VirtualAccount=No"
"ElevatedToken=Yes"
"ImpersonationLevel=Impersonation"
"NewLogon="
"SecurityID=MDITMonSvc"
"AccountName=MonSvc"
"AccountDomain=MD3T.CE-IT.NET"
"LogonID=0xAE5D3D4"
"LinkedLogonID=0x0"
"NetworkAccountName=-"
"NetworkAccountDomain=-"
"LogonGUID={e2fe21c6-1533-f673-af2c-1e289f01739f}"
"ProcessInformation="
"ProcessID=0x0"
"ProcessName=-"
"NetworkInformation="
"WorkstationName=-"
"SourceNetworkAddress=11.300.2.35"
"SourcePort=49357"
"DetailedAuthenticationInformation="
"LogonProcess=Kerberos"
"AuthenticationPackage=Kerberos"
"TransitedServices=-"
"PackageName(NTLMonly)=-"
"KeyLength=0"
```

Comment: This works for the string in my post but the problem is it doesn't seem to work when the text is in another format: "Dns query= RuleName= - UtcTime= 2023-03-14 17=29=56.244 ProcessGuid= {FBA8C56C-AF1D-6410-401C-000000004100} ProcessId= 3892 QueryName= MD2-DC-P3.Churchill.CSG-IT.NET QueryStatus= 0 QueryResults= ==ffff=10.58.2.45; Image= C=Windowssystem32wbemwmiprvse.exe".

Comment: @Kevin I see, I'd say this one would be a slightly different regex since it looks like keys are already in Pascal case (except for `Dns query`), but I don't think there would be a one-size-fits-all solution. Are these the only two event formats you have or are there more?